# Fade image on-load using css3

Tags: html, css

This is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/NVk2N/2/

I'm trying to fade the large background image in. I tried this:

```
#cover {
    background: url(http://bootstrapguru.com/preview/cascade/images/carousel/imageOne.jpg)         no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

however the image never appears. What am I doing wrong?

James

Comment: Do you want the content within the element to fade as well? Or just the background image?

Comment: Sorry, just the background image

Comment: @Jimmy check out my answer edit: I've inserted an example with the animation of the image only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually need an animation of the opacity, in which you set `animation-fill-mode: forwards` so the last frame continues to apply after the final iteration of the animation.

**Updated fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/NVk2N/7/

```
#cover {
    ...
    -webkit-animation: 2s show;
    -moz-animation: 2s show;
    -ms-animation: 2s show;
    animation: 2s show;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}


@-webkit-keyframes show {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
@-moz-keyframes show {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
@-ms-keyframes show {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
@keyframes show {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 1 }
}
```

(of course you need to use vendor prefixes where necessary)

---

**Note**: If you need to fade-in only the **background image** (and not the whole element) you could load the background inside an absolute positioned pseudoelement (e.g. `#cover:before`) with a negative `z-index` and just apply the animation to the psuedoelement itself:

> Here's an example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJayr/

**Relevant CSS**

```
#cover {
    position: relative;
    width   : ...;
    height  : ...;
}

#cover:before {
    content : "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index : -1;
    top     : 0; 
    left    : 0;
    width   : 100%; 
    height  : 100%;

    background: url(...) top left no-repeat;

    -webkit-animation: 5s show;
    -moz-animation: 5s show;
    -ms-animation: 5s show;
    animation: 5s show;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
```

Animations on pseudoelements work fine on every modern browser (except in Chrome < 26 — [as reported on issue #54699](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54699) — but not really a problem, since the current version at this moment is 34.0.1847.116)

Comment: Surely if you use keyframes, this will make the content within the element fade aswell?

Comment: I gave both the code examples. I leave the choice to the OP. I hope he likes cats

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may use [keyframes and animations](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) to get the job done.
It's not possible with purely css to fade only the background image. Reference: [How to fade in background image by CSS3 Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905621/how-to-fade-in-background-image-by-css3-animation)

The answer there explains that you may use `<img>` inside a `<div>` that you apply the fade animation on as there is no other way without anything but css.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use some js code to trigger the animation property. just add a new class for #cover with opacity:1 and on body load assign this class to cover.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/NVk2N/5/)

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('cover').classList.add('showed');">
```

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a transition you actually need a trigger.

You are setting a opacity of "0" and this is what you get: 0 opacity.
The transition would work if the declaration of opacity would change from 0 to 1.
That is what transitions do.

The solution of Fabrizio Calderan with the Animation should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the other answers that have been given will give you a fade on all the elements within that element so this will no achieve your desired result.

The best way to do this is to:

1) Create a div with a z-index of 1 which holds your background image and what you want to fade
2) Create another div with a z-index of 10 which holds your content which you dont want to fade and position it over the background div with position absolute. 
3) Animate the background image with jquery animate

I hope this helps and that will give you your desired outcome!

Comment: He could avoid to use an empty div for the image and use only a pseudoelement (since it's for style purpose only). Why should he animate the image with jQuery `animate()`?