# css transition background change not fading in smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fade in a new background of a header when the user scrolls down. I would like it to fade in smoothly on top of the original background.

Instead what is happening, is that it is removing the original background and then fading in the new one. This makes the transition look ugly when the user scrolls down...

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar {
  transition:  background 0.5s ease-in 0s;
}

.navbar {
  background: url("images/nav-bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1600px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

}
.navbar.fade-blue {

    background:#566c75;

}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    if ( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
        jQuery(".navbar").addClass("fade-blue");
    } 

    else {
        jQuery(".navbar").removeClass("fade-blue");
    } 
});
});
```

EDIT: I changed the `.fade-blue` class as I had two background rules there, I am attempting to fade a background image into a colour.

Comment: You can't fade one background image into another one, since you can only have one background image at a time (not strictly true, but close enough).

Comment: As @Archer said you can only have on background-image at once but how about adding an other element with your second background-image and fade that element in.

Comment: @Adrian There's 2 images right? An old one and a new one right?
The url in the css seems to be the same..

Comment: sorry my bad, I confused things there, Im going to remove the second url in the `fade-blue` rule, Im trying to fade a background image into a colour

Comment: I did this but there is a wierd flash on chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/4v2Zg/

Comment: Thats pretty much it! , but strange about the Chrome flash

Comment: @Adrian does it flash for you too?

Comment: yea im getting the same flash in Chrome

Comment: @Adrian well, it is pretty wierd but I think it comes from jQuery because when you trigger the event on hover it doesn't flash : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/4v2Zg/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fadeIn/fadeOut your background imgae (A) with another one (B), you need to put both in a separate div, and apply to those the opacity transition.

If you need only to fadeOut your backgorund image, you can only put it on separate element inside parent container, and apply to that the opacity transition.

Here an example
[How to fade in background image by CSS3 Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905621/how-to-fade-in-background-image-by-css3-animation)