# Ways to fade in and out of a dynamic ng-style background-image

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, background-image, ng-style

I have a main div with a dynamic ng-style background-image like so:

```
<div class="modal slide-in-up profile-view" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + jobTypeSelected.backgroundImagePath + ')'}" ng-controller="tasksCtrl">
....
</div>
```

The backgroundImagePath is changing based on user select option. Everything works. But the image just shows up with the background-image setting. Is there a way to add animation on the ng-style background image transition? Like add a fadein and fadeout to smooth out the transition? I can not just set the opacity of the div as it contains all the content of this page (an Ionic popup). Any suggestion how I should approach this?

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fade in background image by CSS3 Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905621/how-to-fade-in-background-image-by-css3-animation)